# How can I replace coloured tiles with images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I am currently creating a tile based dungeon crawler and I want to start adding images to the current build. I am using vanilla JavaScript. I have all the images prepped and just want to know how to add them to the canvas here:

```
  for (var y = 0; y < mapH; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < mapW; x++) {
      switch (gameMap[((y * mapW) + x)]) {
        case 0:
          ctx.fillStyle = '#999999'
          break
        default:
          ctx.fillStyle = '#eeeeee'
          break
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH)
    }
  }
```

If you want all my code here it is:

```
// Main Variables
var ctx = null
var tileW = 40
var tileH = 40
var mapW = 10
var mapH = 10

// Frame Variables
var currentSecond = 0
var frameCount = 0
var framesLastSecond = 0
var lastFrameTime = 0

// Inputs
var keysDown = {
  87: false,
  65: false,
  83: false,
  68: false
}

// Characters
var player = new Character()

// Game Variables
var gameMap = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
]

function Character () {
  this.tileFrom = [1, 1]
  this.tileTo = [1, 1]
  this.timeMoved = 0
  this.dimensions = [30, 30]
  this.position = [45, 45]
  this.delayMove = 700
}
Character.prototype.placeAt = function (x, y) {
  this.tileFrom = [x, y]
  this.tileTo = [x, y]
  this.position = [((tileW * x) + ((tileW - this.dimensions[0]) / 2)), ((tileH * y) + ((tileH - this.dimensions[1]) / 2))]
}
Character.prototype.processMovement = function (t) {
  if (this.tileFrom[0] === this.tileTo[0] && this.tileFrom[1] === this.tileTo[1]) {
    return false
  }
  if ((t - this.timeMoved) >= this.delayMove) {
    this.placeAt(this.tileTo[0], this.tileTo[1])
  }
  else {
    this.position[0] = (this.tileFrom[0] * tileW) + ((this.tileW - this.dimensions[0]) / 2)
    this.position[1] = (this.tileFrom[1] * tileH) + ((this.tileh - this.dimensions[1]) / 2)

    if (this.tileTo[0] !== this.tileFrom[0]) {
      var diff = (tileW / this.delayMove) * (t - this.timeMoved)
      this.position[0] += (this.tileTo[0] < this.tileFrom[0] ? 0 - diff : diff)
    }
    if (this.tileTo[1] !== this.tileFrom[1]) {
      var diff = (tileW / this.delayMove) * (t - this.timeMoved)
      this.position[1] += (this.tileTo[1] < this.tileFrom[1] ? 0 - diff : diff)
    }
    this.position[0] = Math.round(this.position[0])
    this.position[1] = Math.round(this.position[1])
  }
  return true
}

function toIndex (x, y) {
  return ((y * mapW) + x)
}

window.onload = function () {
  ctx = document.getElementById('game').getContext('2d')
  requestAnimationFrame(drawGame)
  ctx.font = 'bold 10pt sans-serif'

  window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 63 && e.keyCode <= 87) {
      keysDown[e.keyCode] = true
    }
  })
  window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 63 && e.keyCode <= 87) {
      keysDown[e.keyCode] = false
    }
  })
}

function drawGame () {
  if (ctx == null) { return }

  var currentFrameTime = Date.now()
  var timeElapsed = currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime

  var sec = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)

  if (sec !== currentSecond) {
    currentSecond = sec
    framesLastSecond = frameCount
    frameCount = 1
  }
  else { frameCount++ }

  if (!player.processMovement(currentFrameTime)) {
    if (keysDown[87] && player.tileFrom[1] > 0 && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0], player.tileFrom[1] - 1)] === 1) {
      player.tileTo[1] -= 1
    }
    else if (keysDown[83] && player.tileFrom[1] < (mapH - 1) && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0], player.tileFrom[1] + 1)] === 1) {
      player.tileTo[1] += 1
    }
    else if (keysDown[65] && player.tileFrom[0] > 0 && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0] - 1, player.tileFrom[1])] === 1) {
      player.tileTo[0] -= 1
    }
    else if (keysDown[68] && player.tileFrom[0] < (mapW - 1) && gameMap[toIndex(player.tileFrom[0] + 1, player.tileFrom[1])] === 1) {
      player.tileTo[0] += 1
    }
    if (player.tileFrom[0]!=player.tileTo[0] || player.tileFrom[1]!=player.tileTo[1]) {
      player.timeMoved = currentFrameTime
    }
  }

  for (var y = 0; y < mapH; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < mapW; x++) {
      switch (gameMap[((y * mapW) + x)]) {
        case 0:
          ctx.fillStyle = '#999999'
          break
        default:
          ctx.fillStyle = '#eeeeee'
          break
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x * tileW, y * tileH, tileW, tileH)
    }
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = '#0000ff'
  ctx.fillRect(player.position[0], player.position[1], player.dimensions[0], player.dimensions[1])

  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000'
  ctx.fillText('FPS: ' + framesLastSecond, 10, 20)

  lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime
  requestAnimationFrame(drawGame)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the images in the HTML body of your code as such:

```
<section hidden>
 <img id="img1" src="img1.png"/>
 <img id="img2" src="img2.png"/>
</section>
```

<section hidden> makes it so the images don't get drawn in the body

src="img1.png" searches for the file "img1.png" in the same folder as your HTML is in.
 If you want to put the images in a folder within that folder (let's say a folder named "textures") you can do src="textures\img1.png"

Then you can use ctx.drawImage like this:

```
for (var y = 0; y < mapH; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < mapW; x++) {
    let img
    switch (gameMap[((y * mapW) + x)]) {
      case 0:
        img = document.getElementById("img1")
        break
      default:
        img = document.getElementById("img2")
        break
    }
    ctx.drawImage(img,x * tileW, y * tileH)
  }
}
```

[drawImage Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)